# How can I open a extra console and run a program in it cpp

Tags: c++, console, console-application, system

I write a program that checks when another program is running and how much its CPU usage is.  So, I want my own program and that other program should be able to run at the same time.

But, when I run another console application from my own console application by using the `system()` function or using this code:

```
STARTUPINFO info = {sizeof(info)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
if (CreateProcess("AppName", "start", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)) {
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
```

The opened program continues in my own program's console, which means my own program stops until that other program is done (is not at the same time).

Comment: `system()` is a blocking function, it waits until the requested command is finished. So does using `WaitForSingleObject(INFINITE)` after `CreateProcess()`.  So, if you don't want to block your program, don't use blocking functions.  In the case of calling `CreateProcess()` directly, use the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` or `DETACHED_PROCESS` flag to run the spawned program separate from the calling program's console.

Comment: Completely fixed.
Thanks for your explanation.